# Android - saving an image to card throws an error

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to save an image to card and I get the error "< file path > (IS A DIRECTORY)" altough the file's absolute path is correct and the file is an image and not a directory. What am I doing wrong here? I need to mention that I create all the necessary directories before saving the image to disk and I have all the permissions.

```
file.getAbsolutePath() //returns something like this:

/mnt/sdcard/app_name/folder/image.jpg
```

..
I construct the picture file like this: `File img = new File(dir, image.jpg);`

```
public static void saveImg(File pic, Bitmap picture) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Logcat output.

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/Droste/Report_1343677354477/media/Büro/Wohnzimmer_Building_image_1344030487904.jpg (Is a directory)

Comment: Did you define permission to store external in your manifest?

Comment: He says he has all the permissions.

Comment: yes, I have no problems saving other files

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/app_name/folder/image.jpg does not look much like /mnt/sdcard/Droste/Report_1343677354477/media/Büro/

Comment: its just two more nested folders, makes no difference does it?

Comment: You might be having problems with creating your directories and there might even be a directory called image.jpg. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to check your sd card to see if you really have a directory with that name (in case you are calling mkdirs() on the image file before creating the stream by any chance).

Then, you can try using this code to create your stream:

```
String fileName = "image.jpg";
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path, fileName);
path.mkdirs();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: it worked. I wasn't calling mkDirs() on the parent directory. Thank you!